# DELETE removes less rows than it has to

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-delete

I have a task to delete rows in one table based on condition between two tables (I join on more than one column because there are no PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEYs:

```
DELETE rf 
FROM #tempTable rf 
LEFT JOIN #tempTableInc rfi 
    ON rf.ID = rfi.ID
    AND rf.Code = rfi.Code 
    AND rf.Type = rfi.Type
    AND rf.Year = rfi.Year
WHERE rfi.Value != rf.Value
```

If I only write this code:

```
SELECTrf.*, rfi.Value rfi
FROM #tempTable rf 
    LEFT JOIN #tempTableInc rfi 
        ON rf.ID = rfi.ID
        AND rf.Code = rfi.Code 
        AND rf.Type = rfi.Type
        AND rf.Year = rfi.Year
    WHERE rfi.Value != rf.Value
```

I receive for example 30 records. When I write it in the `DELETE` statement I delete only 26 records. What could be the reason for this disparity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the discrepancy is that the `JOIN` might produce multiple rows for a give row in `rf`.  Even though the `SELECT` returns those rows, only one is deleted.

Note that a `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary for this logic, because the `WHERE` clause requires that there be a match, turning the outer join into an inner join.

You can get a more accurate count using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT rf.*
FROM #tempTable rf 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM #tempTableInc rfi 
              WHERE rf.ID = rfi.ID AND
                    rf.Code = rfi.Code AND
                    rf.Type = rfi.Type AND
                    rf.Year = rfi.Year AND
                    rfi.Value <> rf.Value
             );
```

Comment: Is this fixable?

Comment: @Yana . . . The `DELETE` is doing the right thing.  Nothing needs to be fixed.

Comment: When I write the second query from my question using `EXISTS`, I receive different result. Does `EXISTS` give more accurate answer than join when it comes to a tasks like this?

Comment: @yana . . . The `exists` only counts each row in `rf` once.  It cannot produce duplicates.

Comment: Then what does LEFT JOIN do, why does it return bigger count?

Comment: @Yana . . . The issue is not the `LEFT JOIN` because the `WHERE` clause turns it into an `INNER JOIN`.  I tried to explain that in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224098/discussion-between-yana-and-gordon-linoff).